# MySQL: Advisable number of rows

Tags: mysql, performance, database-design, optimization

Consider an indexed MySQL table with 7 columns, being constantly queried and written to. What is the advisable number of rows that this table should be allowed to contain before the performance would be improved by splitting the data off into other tables?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Whether or not you would get a performance gain by partitioning the data depends on the data and the queries you will run on it. You can store many millions of rows in a table and with good indexes and well-designed queries it will still be super-fast. Only consider partitioning if you are already confident that your indexes and queries are as good as they can be, as it can be more trouble than its worth.

Comment: I've accepted this answer because it seems the most pragmatic. Other people have given factors to look out for which is useful, but you can't always be around when things go wrong, so I feel that the best literal answer to my question is "a few million".

Answer (score 3):

There's no magic number, but there's a few things that affect performance in particular:

- Index Cardinality: don't bother indexing a row that has 2 or 3 values (like an ENUM). On a large table, the query optimizer will ignore these.
- There's a trade off between writes and indexes. The more indexes you have, the longer writes take. Don't just index every column. Analyze your queries and see which columns need to be indexed for your app.
- Disk IO and a memory play an important role. If you can fit your whole table into memory, you take disk IO out of the equation (once the table is cached, anyway). My guess is that you'll see a big performance change when your table is too big to buffer in memory.
- Consider partitioning your servers based on use. If your transactional system is reading/writing single rows, you can probably buy yourself some time by replicating the data to a read only server for aggregate reporting.

As you probably know, table performance changes based on the data size. Keep an eye on your table/queries. You'll know when it's time for a change.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL 5 has [partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html) built in and is very nice.  What's nice is you can define how your table should be split up.  For instance, if you query mostly based on a userid you can partition your tables based on userid, or if you're querying by dates do it by date.  What's nice about this is that MySQL will know exactly which partition table to search through to find your values.  The downside is if you're search on a field that isn't defining your partition its going to scan through each table, which could possibly decrease performance.

Answer (score 0):

While after the fact you could point to the table size at which performance became a problem, I don't think you can predict it, and certainly not from the information given on a web site such as this!

Some questions you might usefully ask yourself:

- Is performance currently acceptable?
- How is performance measured - is
  there a metric?
- How do we recognise
  unacceptable performance?
- Do we
  measure performance in any way that
  might allow us to forecast a
  problem?
- Are all our queries using
  an efficient index?
- Have we simulated extreme loads and volumes on the system?

Answer (score 0):

Using the MyISAM engine, you'll run into a 2GB hard limit on table size unless you change the default.

Answer (score 0):

Don't ever apply an optimisation if you don't think it's needed. Ideally this should be determined by testing (as others have alluded).

Horizontal or vertical partitioning can improve performance but also complicate you application. Don't do it unless you're sure that you need it AND it will definitely help.

The 2G data MyISAM file size is only a default and can be changed at table creation time (or later by an ALTER, but it needs to rebuild the table). It doesn't apply to other engines (e.g. InnoDB).

Comment: "Don't ever apply an optimisation if you don't think it's needed" - Perhaps in the context of splitting off a database table and being unsure as to what it will do, but in general surely this is terrible advice?  Wait for something to go wrong/slow before you then spend a few hours/days fixing it?

Comment: I'm not advocating "waiting for something to go wrong", but rather doing some performance testing to evaluate whether further optimisation is needed. In many cases people apply unnecessary optimisations, which add code complexity (reducing maintainability and increasing the chance of bugs) .

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is a good question for performance. Have you read [Jay Pipes](http://www.jpipes.com/)? There isn't a specific number of rows but there is a specific page size for reads and there can be good reasons for vertical partitioning.

Check out his kung fu presentation and have a look through his posts. I'm sure you'll find that he's written some useful advice on this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using MyISAM?  Are you planning to store more than a couple of gigabytes?  Watch out for MAX_ROWS and AVG_ROW_LENGTH.

Jeremy Zawodny has an [excellent write-up](http://jeremy.zawodny.com/blog/archives/000796.html) on how to solve this problem.