# Prevent delete account in AdminCP when it still signing in

Tags: php

I have a problem with delete account in PHP. In details, I develop the back-end admin control panel site, and in it have a function allow delete account in table Admin_Account. But when I delete, it also allows deleting admin account that current logging in admin control panel site. Can someone help me to prevent, don't let it delete an account that is logging in admin?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Delete account admin</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
    include("connect.php");
    $sl="delete from admin where idAdmin=".$_GET['id'];
    if(mysqli_query($con,$sl))
    {
        echo "<script language='javascript'>alert('Delete successful!');";
        echo "location.href='index.php?xem=theloai';</script>";
    }
?>

<?php include('close_ketnoi.php');?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection attacks**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should use [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) prepared statements with bound parameters as described in [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Answer (score 0):

Two things
1) Never delete account from table, instead do soft delete ([What is the best way to implement soft deletion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68323/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-soft-deletion))
2) While you fire query, you can check if $_GET['id'] is not equal to user_id in session.

Also check for code vulnerabilities, it has many holes.